# Apache Ignite: Classloader

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader, ignite

From reading the documentation on Apache Ignite, I was under the impression that classes I used (for instance) in Eclipse, would automatically (dare I say, Magically?) sent to the distributed instances of the Ignite server.

I have 3 vanilla servers, no custom classes loaded running (./bin/ignite.sh) , all on a localhost.  They peer very nicely.

I run an Eclipse program with one custom class that I use to load into the caches.  Simple POJO, Serializable, etc.

When I try to run a piece of compute code, the remote servers complain about the class not being in the class loader.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.dms.ignite.batch.model.MessageCustAccount
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8213)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:607)
... 29 more
```

Is there more to the magic?

```
        ExecutorService exec = ignite.executorService(ignite.cluster().forRemotes());

         // Iterate through all words in the sentence and create jobs.
        quickCounter = 10;
         while(it.hasNext() && quickCounter-- > 0){// "Print words using runnable".split(" ")) {
           final String word = it.next();
           // Execute runnable on some node.
           String interna_cache_name = DMSIgniteHelpers.getInstance().getCurrentCacheLocation(ignite, MSG_CUST_ACCT_CACHE);

           exec.submit(new IgniteRunnable() {
             @Override public void run() {
                  String delimeter = "\u0001";
                   String[] lineTokens = word.split("\\"+delimeter);

                    String three_pk = null; 
                    if(lineTokens[2].toString() != null && lineTokens[4].toString() != null && lineTokens[3] != null) {
                            String sor_id = new Integer(lineTokens[2]).toString();
                            String cust_id = new Long(lineTokens[4]).toString();
                            String acct_id = lineTokens[3];
                             three_pk = sor_id + cust_id + acct_id;
                             System.out.println("Looking for ("+sor_id+") ("+cust_id+") ("+acct_id+") : " + three_pk + " ----- ");
                             System.out.println("Going to query cache: " + interna_cache_name);
                             IgniteCache<Integer, MessageCustAccount> msgCustAccountCache = ignite.cache(interna_cache_name);

                             MessageCustAccount a =  sqlQuery(msgCustAccountCache,three_pk);
                            System.out.println("*************=================\n\n"  +  a.toString() + "\n@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$");

                    }
               System.out.println(">>> Printing '" + word + "' on this node from grid job.");
             }
           });
         }
```

Comment: follow up, as expected, I created a JAR file from my source. Put it in the libs folder of Ignite/gridgain, and reran my code. All worked perfectly....   not surprised... but I really was expecting to be able to get this done without that deployment step

Answer (score 3):

Model classes are not peer deployed, but you can use `withKeepBinary()` flag on the cache and query `BinaryObject`s. This way you will avoid deserialization on the server side and will not get `ClassNotFoundException`.

Refer to this example on how this can be done: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/binary/datagrid/CacheClientBinaryQueryExample.java